# What is the equivalent of windows user Favorites directory on Mac OS and linux based OS?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, directory, documents

say in on windows 7 using python language: os.path.expanduser('~') gets me 'E:\Users\san'

and in there is a **Documents** folder so i can get to it by os.join()

what is it called on MAC OSx or other linux distros?

Comment: What's a "Favorites" folder and why do you think it has to exist on other OSes?

Comment: well on windows its where IE store all its favorites so I thought their could be on other OSes too, however if its not Favorite I guess I can look for Documents folder!!! guess I should edit the question text "Favorite" to "Documents"

Comment: Well, are you looking for *the location the browser stores its bookmarks*, or just some location to put documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users directory in UNIX (Mac OS X) and UNIX-like (Linux, et al.) systems is called "Users".
In that directory are the account directories. Typically in OS X, you see the one account directory for the owner of the computer, and another called "Shared". The Shared account is read-write access for everyone.

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents"))
```

The Documents directory for the logged in user is in the user account directory. For OS 10.4.11 or earlier, there is no default Documents directory. Some installations (MS Office, for example) create a Documents directory in older OS versions.
Using UNIX pathway marks for a user called Bob Smith...
/Users/bobsmith/Documents

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be mostly the same. The structure in Unix is similiar, therefore

```
os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents")
```

should take you to the folder. If ~ does not work try HOME or $HOME.